# How can you upgrade multiple units at the same time?

Tags: civilization-5

When upgrading units to a more modern equivalent, is it possible to do a mass upgrade in one go instead of finding and upgrading each individual unit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, however you can use the unit list to find units of the same name
(Military Info <kbd>F3</kbd>) located in the upper left hand corner, The same icon as the "Display Current Technology" turns into a drop down list.

Double clicking on the unit will center the map.